# Error while consuming SOAP service using apache-camel[2.24.3]

Tags: java, spring, soap, apache-camel, weblogic12c

I am getting error while I am trying to consume SOAP service, which is deployed in Jboss EAP 7.1 and My Server with **Apache camel[2.24.3] and spring [5.2.2.RELEASE]**  deployed in **Weblogic12c**. After exchange happend, it needs to give getMandatoryBody() in string format but its returning in DOMSource, where camel is failing to cast DOMService to string.

**The Exception I am getting is :**

```
No body available of type: java.lang.String but has value: javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource@37279c86 of type: javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource on: Message[ID-everest2-1589967071589-0-11]. Caused by: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.lang.String with value [Body is instance of java.xml.transform.Source] due javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed. Exchange[ID-everest2-1589967071589-0-10]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException - Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.lang.String with value [Body is instance of java.xml.transform.Source] due javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed
```

The problem is happening only when i deploy my server[with camel and spring] in weblogic 12c. Other application servers Tomcat 8.5.35 and jboss-EAP7.2 .Its working fine.

I tried by downgrading camel-spring-ws version to [2.17.3] its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception clearly states that from getMandatoryBody() method, you are getting a  javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource type of value and not a String value.
So, you might need to read the value of getMandatoryBody()  as DOMSource.
The conversion from DOMSource to String is easy using the Java Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

//method to convert Document to String
public String getStringFromDocument(DOMSource domSource)
{
    try
    {
       StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
       StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
       TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
       Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
       transformer.transform(domSource, result);
       return writer.toString();
    }
    catch(TransformerException ex)
    {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}
```

If you are sure about the String value in the Exchange, perform a debug on the Exchange object to see what possible values are present there.

Comment: In other application servers(Jboss EAP 7.2 and tomcat 8.5.35) after exchange its returning string value. Only when I use weblogic 12c, this problem arises.  
I tried the above solution its failing to convert to String when its having more data.